# SSH Copy Limit?

Tags: ssh, file-sharing, cp

So I have a small little Ubuntu server set up, with some rather large files that I've allowed a few people to copy from their putty window.

Anyways 2 questions:
Lets say a person on windows wants to copy a file using putty from an Ubuntu server. how would they do it? and what directory would it default too? (what would the command be even? would I use SCP?)

Second question: is there like a limit? these are mostly 1-2gb files. would that cause any issues? Thanks

Comment: for windows people I recommend they use [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) or perhaps an ftp client that supports sftp, like [filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) all of this really just uses scp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [PSCP](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) which comes as part of the PuTTY distribution.

The usage of `pscp` is:

```
pscp [user@]host:source target
```

For example, from a Windows cmd prompt, type the following command to transfer a file to your C: drive.

```
pscp username@host:/path/to/file.txt C:\temp\file.txt
```

I don't believe there is a file size limit.

Comment: Could also use psftp, which some people might find easier (myself, I prefer the scp mechanism).

Answer (score 0):

The default will be the home directory of the linux server account being used.  So if a person used `luser@yourserver:foobar.pdf`, then the file would be taken from/placed at ~luser/foobar on yourserver.

If you do not want people to be able to write to your server, then I suggest locking down the directories/files and/or settings up a callback script inside the .ssh/authorized_keys file.